# Runtime error when trying to format cells in a range

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I am having a lot of trouble with my vba code. I have created a sub that will execute when the file is opened. However, I keep getting a runtime error that says I have an application defined or object-defined problem. This code works when the "With Cells(13, dateFinder.Column)" block is not accompanied by the "With Cells(17, dateFinder.Column)" block below it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub equityRaiseOpen()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("PRESENTATION")
Set ws2 = Worksheets(7)
ws2.Activate
Dim dateRange As Range
ws2.Unprotect
Dim dte As Date


'this block finds current quarter ending date
If Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Month(Now()) / 3, 0) = 1 Then
    dte = DateValue("3/31/" & Year(Now()))
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Month(Now()) / 3, 0) = 2 Then
    dte = DateValue("6/30/" & Year(Now()))
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Month(Now()) / 3, 0) = 3 Then
    dte = DateValue("9/30/" & Year(Now()))
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Month(Now()) / 3, 0) = 4 Then
    dte = DateValue("12/31/" & Year(Now()))
End If


Set dateRange = Range("FFO___AFFO_SUMMARY")

Dim iterator As Range
Dim colNum As Integer

'this block finds the column number for the current quarter ending date
For Each iterator In dateRange
    If iterator = dte Then
        colNum = iterator.Column
    End If
Next

ws2.Range("B1") = dte

Dim dateFinder As Range
Set dateFinder = ws2.Range("B1")
Dim i As Integer
'Call putDates
i = 9

'ws2.Unprotect

Dim j As Integer

Set dateFinder = ws2.Range("B1")

For j = 1 To i
    Cells(12, dateFinder.Column) = 0.4
    'create data validiation for debt source
    Debug.Print Cells(13, dateFinder.Column).Address
    With Cells(13, dateFinder.Column)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Locked = False
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=DebtList"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
            .Value = "Revolver"
        End With
        With Cells(17, dateFinder.Column)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Locked = False
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="ATM,Common, Preferred"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
            .Value = "ATM"
        End With

    Set dateFinder = dateFinder.Offset(0, 2)
Next j



'ws2.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: let's make it clear- which line in your code the error is marked when you press debug?

Comment: the line following: With Cells(17, dateFinder.Column), the second large With block

Comment: are you sure this range is not protected? your code is working ok for me...

Comment: I had tried un-protecting the entire workbook at the beginning of the code but that didn't work. Per your suggestion, I unprotected the sheet in several different places and it eventually worked though I'm not sure why. Thank you very much!